# Call methods based on compareTo?

Tags: java, compare, biginteger

If I use `compareTo` an a `BigInteger`, how can I choose from the outcome which function to call? (-1 = funcA, +1 = funcB, 0 = no function).

Especially: what's wrong with this?

```
doCompare() {
   BigInteger x = new BigInteger(5);
   BigInteger y = new BigInteger(10);

   //syntax error token "<", invalid assignment operator
   x.compareTo(y) < 0 ? funcA() : funcB();
}

void funcA();
void funcB();
```

Comment: Why not take results to temp value and do if/else?

Comment: Cause it's just an example to abstract my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are using `BigInteger()` constructor incorrectly, it takes `String` not `int` or `long`. And your functions must have `boolean` return type, otherwise you cannot use them in ternary operation.

```
   void doCompare() 
    {
       BigInteger x = new BigInteger("5");
       BigInteger y = new BigInteger("10");

       boolean result = x.compareTo(y) < 0 ? funcA() : funcB();
    }

    boolean funcA(){return true;};
    boolean funcB(){return false;};
```

Answer (score 6):

Since `funcA()` and `funcB()` have return type `void`, you can't use [the ternary syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25). You can rewrite it as a regular `if` statement instead though:

```
if (x.compareTo(y) < 0) {
    funcA();
} else {
    funcB();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

> public void doCompare()
>       {
>           BigInteger x = new BigInteger("5");
>           BigInteger y = new BigInteger("10");
>
> ```
>     //syntax error token "<", invalid assignment operator
>     if(x.compareTo(y) < 0 )
>     {
>         funcA();
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         funcB();
>     }
> }
>
> public void funcA()
> {
> }
>
> public void funcB()
> {
> }
> ```

if you want to use the conditional in one line you need modify the functiones:

> ```
> public void doCompare()
> {
>     BigInteger x = new BigInteger("5");
>     BigInteger y = new BigInteger("10");
>
>     boolean a = (x.compareTo(y) < 0 ) ? funcA() : funcB();
>
> }
>
> public boolean funcA()
> {
>     return false;
> }
>
> public boolean funcB()
> {
>     return true;
> }
> ```